# Why does the confirm dialog require two clicks with ujs?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Initially no confirm was coming up.
I found that adding `//= query_ujs` to my asset manifold resolved this.
However... now I find that the confirm dialog takes "2 clicks" to use (either the cancel or the ok buttons).

My manifest looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//
// ujs needed for delete confirm dial boxes.
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Whether it's cancel or OK, it takes two clicks.
The Rails code for the delete button

```
= button_to '', schedule_path(schedule), 
:method => 'delete', 
:confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this schedule?', 
:class => 'deleteicon', 
:title => "Delete #{name}"
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<form action="/schedule/719" class="button_to" method="post">
  <div>
    <input name="_method" value="delete" type="hidden">
    <input class="deleteicon" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this schedule?" title="Delete Shedule A" value="" type="submit">
    <input name="authenticity_token" value="wpcofEiLu6NXymHj289XGahTTT1XqNI56XvBlAFq2G8=" type="hidden">
  </div>
</form>
```

js for page header:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Do you use jquery or something? Maybe it is loaded twice.

Comment: Maybe but I can't find what the issue it.  I've tried changing the order that the js libraries are listed in and I've tried commenting out the other various js libraries and recompiling assets but still no joy.

Comment: Did you try to remove jquery-ui? https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: +1 bill. yeah,good thought, I tried removing that, I also tried removing the jquery reference itself and just leaving the //= for jquery_ujs but neither of these worked.  Good idea though.

Comment: You could try making the popup, or whatever it is, movable and see if there is two :) Or simply check the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was **asset compilation.**

Our system is set to automatically compile assets during runtime.

I had (mistakenly) also done a `rake assets:precompile` so I had basically duplicated the js and created the duplicate.  I noticed at the time theta the precompile that it created a lot of files which was a red flag as to why things had changed and the double click had started (although when precompile *is* used, it has its place).

Thanks to git I was able to revert to master, rebranch anew with a new branch name and just not do the precompile step.